# Oracle SQL Developer PL/SQL return an array

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure, cursors

Devs,

I've searched everywhere I can, but I could not find solution to this simple problem.

**Situation:**

**I need to write a procedure where it takes a column name as the input and return all the distinct values present in that column as output. And then I have to use this procedure in some c# code.**

In MS server, it is very easy as it will directly give the set of results unlike in PL/SQL.

Script I could write (which is not giving me the result I need):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE GetCol(PARAM IN STRING, recordset OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN recordset FOR
SELECT DISTINCT(PARAM)
FROM my_table;
END
```

;

When I try to check the data in the recordset using this code:

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_sname VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  GetCol('col_name',l_cursor);
    LOOP 
    FETCH l_cursor INTO  l_sname;
    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_sname);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE
```

Can someone help me with this code please.

Comment: The logic looks correct, but your select statement is strange.  If you run "select distinct('col_name') from my_table" what do you get?  You need to do an execute immediate instead.

Comment: I just need to get all the unique values from that particular column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also open a ref_cursor for a string value. Please take a look at this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetCol(PARAM IN VARCHAR2, recordset OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
QRY varchar2(100);
BEGIN
QRY := 'SELECT DISTINCT '||PARAM||' FROM my_table';
OPEN recordset FOR QRY;
END;
```

Then:

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_sname VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  GetCol('col_name',l_cursor);
    LOOP 
    FETCH l_cursor INTO  l_sname;
    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_sname);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by ambiguity about what `PARAM` is in the procedure's SELECT statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE GetCol(PARAM IN STRING, recordset OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN recordset FOR
SELECT DISTINCT(PARAM) -- Ambiguity here
FROM my_table;
END;
```

Does `PARAM` refer to the table column or to the first parameter of the procedure?  Oracle has assumed the parameter. You can explicitly say which like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(my_table.PARAM) 
FROM my_table;
```

You could if appropriate (it probably isn't here) specify the procedure parameter instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(GetCol.PARAM) 
FROM my_table;
```

Generally this is best avoided by:

- always using table aliases in column references select statements, and
- having a standard for parameter names that makes them less likely to clash e.g. P_PARAM.

Comment: PARAM here, is the column name and also the only IN parameter for the procedure. When ever user gives a column name, procedure should return all the distinct values present in that particular column.